# How can i represent the interactions between my modules on a diagram

Tags: architecture, uml, diagram

I have 5 high level modules.  I want to show how they interact on one diagram.

For example module 1 sends module 2 a certain data class via an interface.

How do I represent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [UML Component Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_diagram).  They allow you to depict relations among components as required & provided interfaces.  The interfaces are typed - so you can capture the data types that pass across the links.

hth.

Answer (score 1):

As @sfinnie suggested, component diagrams are a good idea, if you want to focus on showing the structures of components and interfaces and only show an overview of how they interact.

As an alternative to using provided/required interfaces, you can draw `<<flow>>` relationships between the entities and (depending on the modelling tool) show the type of data which flows along that connection.

If you want to show more details of each respective interaction, sequence diagrams are useful; they show individual messages and the order in which they occur. You can use your components and interfaces in sequence diagrams.

Finally, if you want to provide an abstract description of the communication, you might use an activity diagram or an interaction overview diagram. Then you won't use UML components, but instead describe the interaction in terms of "this happens, followed by that, then maybe the other." This is probably the least good fit for your situation, but I'm including it for completeness.